# Oracle sql query need like this

Tags: sql, oracle

```
26337   1111111111  TEST1   111
26331   2222222222  TEST1   222 
23042   3333333333  TEST2   333
```

I need query on above table(user_table) like this.

Frist two records have same value except slno,in that slno if code is same means, i need to get the max number of the values.

```
26337   1111111111  TEST1   111 
23042   3333333333  TEST2   333
```

Comment: Do you say 1111111111  is the same value as 2222222222 ?!?

Comment: @jarlh, No. He meant TEST1 is same for first 2 rows.

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, _not_ as images...

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query -

```
SELECT SLNO, Customer, code, amt
  FROM (SELECT T.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY SLNO) RN
          FROM YOUR_TABLE)
 WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: @Jakka, Most welcome.

Comment: You should then accept/upvote that answer, @Jakka.